# How to find a probability of no passengers flying Delta in a given week?

Tags: probability, mathematical-modeling

I've been given an assignment to model weekly passenger activity on three airlines: Delta, United and American.

**The situation:**

100 business travelers are followed during their weekly flights. No passengers leave or enter the system.

Delta:
75% of passengers who fly Delta on a given week choose to fly Delta the following week. 20% choose American the following week and 5% choose United.

United:
60% of passengers who fly United remain on United the following week. 20% choose to fly Delta and 20% choose to fly American the following week.

American:
40% of American passengers remain on American the following week. 20% switch to United and 40% switch to Delta.

**The question:**

What is the probability that no passenger flies Delta in week 10?

**My work so far:**

The initial distribution is even for all three weeks. I have set up my coefficient matrix $A$ with the numbers above, found my diagonal matrix $B$ such that $A=P^{-1}BP$ and written the equation to find the distribution for any given week $n$: $\pi_n = A^n\pi_0 = PB^nP^{-1}\pi_0$, where $\pi_0 = [1/3,1/3,1/3]$

Plugging into wolfram (which I'm allowed to do) I've gotten the distribution at week 10. I am not sure of the next step. My guess is that if I find the probability that one passenger flies Delta in week 10 I can subtract that probability from one and raise the result to the 100th power?

Comment: first statement is missing 5% of the population.  70+20+5=95.

Comment: @karakfa fixed the typo.

Comment: In order to have a perfectly even initial distribution, you would need $33\frac13$ passengers on each airline. The initial distribution should have been part of the problem statement.

Comment: For 100 passengers you may need to worry about rounding the fractional values, makes to problem very hard,I doubt that's intended.  My guess is treat this as frequencies and use as probability.  Assuming independence your approach seems right.

Comment: Is there a typo in the second one? Did you mean "60% of passengers who fly United..." ?

Comment: I should have re-read my typed question 15 more times than I did. Yes that's also a typo.