# Why is my equilibrium distribution wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, mathematical-modeling

I have a matrix of probability coefficients that I have been using to answer some questions about an airline mode. A link to the [specifics of the question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2907931/how-to-find-a-probability-of-no-passengers-flying-delta-in-a-given-week). I have been asked to find the equilibrium distribution and prove that it equals the limiting distribution. I have found the limiting distribution by:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} A^n\pi_0 = (PB^nP^{-1})\pi_0$$

where $\pi_0$ is the initial distribution. This worked out really well and my vector had elements that added up to 1, which gave me peace of mind.

Now I am trying to find the equilibrium distribution.

As I understand it, I should think about the equilibrium distribution as one that does not change from iteration to iteration: $A\pi = \pi$:

So $(A-I)\pi = 0$. No big deal! This is just like solving for the eigenvector for the eiganvalue $\lambda =1$, which I already did in order to find the limiting distribution by way of $P^{-1}AP$!

So the limiting distribution should be equal to the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue of one... Except that it's not. Where is my thinking wrong here?

Comment: I found my error. My answer was correct but I needed to multiply my eigenvector by a scalar of 1/4 to get the elements to add to one. Sorry for the silly question.

Comment: To keep the question from hanging around unanswered, you could either write up your answer and accept it (which would be preferable if you feel that others might benefit from the insight you gained) or delete the question (if you feel that this was just a specific mistake whose resolution is unlikely to be of benefit to anyone else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply had to multiply the eigenvector by a scalar in order to get a valid probability distribution, such that the elements of the distribution added to 1.